# Have a mapper not map a field in particular conditions

Tags: java, jpa, orika

I have a very particular use case where I have in my hands an object `a` of class `A` and an object `b` of class `B`, such that `a.b.equals(b)` and I intend to map `a` to class `C` using Orika.
The tricky bit is, I'd like to prevent `a.b` from being passed along and rather insert it by myself (`a.b` is actually fetched by JPA during the mapping which I'd like not to happen). On the other hand, I'd like to have `a.b` mapped in all other use cases.

Is there a decent way to implement that sort of behavior in Orika without specifying two custom `ClassMap`s?

Answer (score 2):

One of the possible solutions is to use a `CustomMapper`:

```
mapperFactory.classMap(A.class, C.class)
    .byDefault() // or your explicit mappings
    .exclude("b") // exclude the property from default mapping
    .customize(
       new CustomMapper<A, C> {
          public void mapAtoB(A a, C c, MappingContext context) {
             // implement your own logic for mapping the b property
          }
       }
    .register();
```

See the "Customizing individual ClassMaps" section of the [User Guide](http://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/advanced-mappings.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use ClassMapBuilder.exclude(String propertyName).

Comment: as mentioned, I'd like to have but one `ClassMap`